# Decode a ASCII string with Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii, decoding, string-decoding

I'm fairly new to Python so I'm probably still making a lot of rookie mistakes.

I was comparing two seemingly matching strings in Python, but it always returned false. When I checked the representation of the object, I found that one of the strings was encoded in ASCII.

The representation of the first string returns:

```
'\x00"\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00r\x00y\x00_\x00o\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00_\x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00_\x00b\x00u\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00n\x00"\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00"\x00L\x00a\x00u\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00"\x00;\x00'
```

While the representation of the second string returns:

```
"itinerary_options_search_button" = "Launch the search";
```

I'm trying to figure out how to decode the first string to get the second string, so that my comparison of the two will match.
When I decode the first string with

```
string.decode('ascii')
```

I get a unicode object. I'm not sure what to do to get the decoded string.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. `string.decode('ascii')` should give you the decoded string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first string seems to have some issues. I'm not entirely sure why there is so many null characters (`\x00`), but either way, we could write a function to clean those up:

```
s_1 = '\x00"\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00r\x00y\x00_\x00o\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00_\x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00_\x00b\x00u\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00n\x00"\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00"\x00L\x00a\x00u\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00"\x00;\x00'
s_2 = '"itinerary_options_search_button" = "Launch the search";'

def null_cleaner(string):
    new_string = ""
    for char in string:
        if char != "\x00":
            new_string += char
    return new_string

print(null_cleaner(s_1) == null_cleaner(s_2))
```

A little bit less robust way of doing this is to simply splice the string to remove every other character (which happens to be `\x00`):

```
s_1 = '\x00"\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00r\x00y\x00_\x00o\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00_\x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00_\x00b\x00u\x00t\x00t\x00o\x00n\x00"\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00"\x00L\x00a\x00u\x00n\x00c\x00h\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00"\x00;\x00'
s_2 = '"itinerary_options_search_button" = "Launch the search";'

print(s_1[1::2] == s_2)
```

Comment: I didn't know \x00 was a null character. What I didn't understand was why the output of repr() was returning all these null characters.

Answer (score 0):

> ... encoded in ASCII.
>
> ```
> [lots of NULs]
> ```

Nope.

```
>>> '\x00"\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00r\x00y'.decode('utf-16be')
u'"itinerary'
```

Of course, your data has an extra NUL that will break it. Once you clean that up you should be able to decode it with no problem.